# WinWait inside remote desktop connection

Tags: autoit

In my script I need to connect to a server through RDC, then open an application say abc and wait for a window to appear having title as "Information". I am using:

```vb
WinActive("abc")
Sleep(1000)
WinWaitActive("Information")
```

But it don't seem to identify windows title inside Remote desktop connection. How to control this?

Comment: You should use the [AutoIt Window Information Tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to see, whether you can use the `Win...(...)`-functions to handle a specific window, in this case a remote window. Probably you just have to use [`Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)`](http://www.autoit.de/dokumentation_aktuell/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm) to make it work.

Comment: You could also try to edit/develop your script on the remote server. If it works, then you start it from your local PC via PSexec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to detect a window title inside a RDP. You can write/developp your script on the remote Server.